# Trying to run executemany for insert into returning value in Oracle with Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, insert, cx-oracle

Good Morning,

I am trying to find a way to do an insert into returning SQL statement in python. I would like to use executemany,but my code is rather unworkable at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the SQL to create the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE1
   (    F1 NUMBER(*,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1, 
    F2 NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "TABLE1_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("F1")
   )
```

The Python code is:

```
import cx_Oracle

def makeCxDSNLessConnection(src):
    return cx_Oracle.connect(user=sUser, password=sPass ,dsn=src)
def tempDoit():
    oraCon = makeCxDSNLessConnection('EPAT')
    cur = oraCon.cursor()
    thislist=list()
    thisOut = cur.var(int)
    cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE1")
    for i in range(1000000):
        thislist.append((i,))
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO TABLE1(F2) VALUES(:1) RETURNING F1 INTO :2", thislist, thisOut )
    oraCon.commit()
    while True:
        rows = cur.fetchmany(100)
        if not rows:
            break
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
```

Comment: You have `:1` and `:2` in your query, but the elements of `thislist` only have one value for each row. What is `:2` supposed to correspond to?

Comment: And it makes no sense to use a parameter number for `RETURNING F1 INTO`. You can only return into SQL variable, but parameters are replaced with literals.

Comment: If you want to get the results of multiple inserts, you have to return into a collection.  See https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause#collections

Comment: something like this:```DECLARE DAID INTEGER; CUR1 sys_refcursor; BEGIN INSERT INTO TABLE1(F2) VALUES(:1) RETURNING F1 INTO DAID; OPEN CUR1 FOR SELECT DAID  FROM DUAL; dbms_sql.return_result(CUR1); END;``` ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an Oracle programmer, I just searched for this in the documentation. I can't help with the specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the proper python code:

```
import cx_Oracle

def makeCxDSNLessConnection(src):
    return cx_Oracle.connect(user=sUser, password=sPass ,dsn=src)

def tempDoit():
    oraCon = makeCxDSNLessConnection('EPAT')
    cur = oraCon.cursor()
    thislist=list()
    thisOut =cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING,arraysize=10000)
    cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE1")
    for i in range(10000):
        thislist.append({'F2':i,'F1':thisOut})
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO TABLE1(F2) VALUES(:F2) RETURNING F1 INTO :F1", thislist)
    print(thisOut.values)
    oraCon.commit()
```

Comment: If this is a new project, upgrade to the latest version of cx_Oracle, now called python-oracledb.  The new default Thin mode could be faster for data uploads. See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  Also see the driver documentation about [batch uploading](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html), in particular about [RETURNING INTO](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#dml-returning).